# xamarin control refresh asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, mvvm, unity-container

I am developing a Xamarin app using Prism Unity. I am facing problem on Refreshing the binding of view after my method is called OnNavigatedTo event in my ViewModel class. I am using Fody for property changed. PFB the code snippet:

Model:

```cs
public class Load : BindableBase
{
public string proNumber {get; set;}
...
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public Load load {get; set;}

public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
load = await retrieveTrip();//this service takes much amount of time
//load = Task.Run(async()=>await retrieveTrip()).Result; //if we do this it 
//works fine but it lacks asynchronus way
}
```

The View has binding of the Load object.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="5" Padding="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding load.proNumber,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelContentStyle}"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

If we call the service method async way the label text always comes blank. But on synchronus calling it works as expected.

Comment: Could you please write more clearly your issue?

Comment: I have edited for more clarity.